# Navigation timeout error in puppeteer node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Im trying to scrape a website using puppeter but it keep geting timeout error after a while.

Error - TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
at Timeout.<anonymous> (/content/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/Deferred.js:27:33)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

(async () => {
// Define the keysToExtract array before using it
const keysToExtract = [
'Dimensions',
'Weight',
'SoC',
'CPU',
'Cores',
'GPU',
'RAM',
'Storage',
'Memory cards',
'Display',
'Battery',
'OS',
'Camera',
'SIM card',
'Wi-Fi',
'USB',
'Bluetooth',
'Positioning',
// Add more keys as needed
];

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
const page = await browser.newPage();
const userAgent =
'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)';
await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);

const startUrl = 'https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/brand-more';
await page.goto(startUrl);
console.log('Navigated to:', startUrl);

const brandLinks = await page.$$eval(
'.brand-listing-container-news a',
(links) => links.map((a) => a.href)
);

// Flag to keep track if headers are written to CSV
let headersWritten = false;

// Initialize the header based on keysToExtract
const header = keysToExtract.map(key => ({ id: key, title: key }));

// Create the CSV writer with the correct header
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
path: 'device_details.csv',
header: header,
append: true, // Append mode to add data without overwriting
});

for (const brandLink of brandLinks) {
await page.goto(brandLink);
console.log('Navigated to:', brandLink);

    const deviceLinks = await page.$$eval(
      'div.model-listing-container-80 h3 a',
      (links) => links.map((a) => a.href)
    );
    
    for (const deviceLink of deviceLinks) {
      await page.goto(deviceLink);
      console.log('Navigated to:', deviceLink);
    
      // Wait for the relevant content to load
      await page.waitForSelector('div#model-brief-specifications');
    
      const deviceDetails = {};
    
      const promises = keysToExtract.map(async (key) => {
        deviceDetails[key] = await page.evaluate((key) => {
          const specItems = document.querySelectorAll('div#model-brief-specifications b');
          for (const item of specItems) {
            const itemKey = item.textContent.trim();
            if (itemKey === key) {
              return item.nextSibling.textContent.trim();
            }
          }
          return ''; // Return an empty string if the key is not found
        }, key);
      });
    
      // Wait for all promises to resolve
      await Promise.all(promises);
    
      // Log the key-value pairs
      console.log(deviceDetails);
    
      // Write to CSV
      if (!headersWritten) {
        csvWriter.writeRecords([header]).then(() => {
          console.log('CSV headers have been written successfully.');
        });
        headersWritten = true;
      }
    
      csvWriter.writeRecords([deviceDetails]).then(() => {
        console.log('CSV data has been appended successfully.');
      });
    }

}

await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Please [edit] to fix your code syntax. Thanks. Where is the timeout error pointing?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are looping through a lot of links. Is possible that the website is blocking you after some requests because *your are browsing too fast to be an human*.

A simple workaround would be to wait some time between each navigation. That's how i usually do:

```js
for (const brandLink of brandLinks) {

    // the previous code
    // ...

    // wait some time before browsing next page
    await wait(3000)
}

// a simple wait function
async function wait(millisec) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, millisec))
}
```

You could use a random timeout value to enhance your browsing *humanity*